# onCharacteristicRead error 129 when connecting to multiple BLE devices

Tags: android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to read Bluetooth low energy characteristics from multiple similar BLE devices (like http://www.blehome.com/sensorbug-PC.html). My app scans for and finds the devices and then creates a map of devices to manage the data for each device (BluetoothGatt, BluetoothGattService, and the data values returned by readCharacteristic() calls).  The code is working for the first device it connects to, but on connections to additional devices, I get a status==129 in the onCharacteristicRead callback. If I switch the order of devices, it works for the first but not the second devices, so I'm suspecting something in either my code or the Android BLE layer.  I've tried on multiple phones and tablets (Google Pixel 4.2, Nokia 7.2, and Samsung Galaxy TabA) with similar results.  I'll try and attach the relevant code.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String[] targetDevices = {"EC:FE:7E:10:90:7C", "EC:FE:7E:10:93:47", "EC:FE:7E:10:92:F1"};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
... 
code to scan for devices and populate an arrayadapter to show a list of available devices to the user.  This part is working great.
...
// MyServiceConnection is a thin wrapper around ServiceConnection to handle the binding of  the BleService to the Activity via an Intent
        mBleServiceConnection = new MyServiceConnection();

        // Start the BLE Service
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting BLE Service");
        Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BleService.class);
        r=bindService(gattServiceIntent, mBleServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(gattServiceIntent);
}

    View.OnClickListener onClickStartBLEService = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            BleService bleService = mBleServiceConnection.getBleservice();

            // Look for each of my devices
            for (String devAddrTarget : targetDevices) {
                for (BluetoothDevice btDev : btDevArrayAdapter.btDevList) {
                    String deviceAddress = btDev.getAddress();
                    if (deviceAddress.equalsIgnoreCase(devAddrTarget)) {
                        bleService.connectToDevice(deviceAddress);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener onClickGetCharacteristics = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean result;

                BleService bleService = mBleServiceConnection.getBleservice();

                result = bleService.readLightDataCharacteristic(targetDevices[0]);
                if (!result) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onClickGetCharacteristics readLightDataCharacteristic result==false");
                }
    };

    View.OnClickListener onClickGetCharacteristicD2 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean result;
                BleService bleService = mBleServiceConnection.getBleservice();

                result = bleService.readLightDataCharacteristic(targetDevices[1]);
                if (!result) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onClickGetCharacteristics readLightDataCharacteristic result==false");
                }
        }
    };
}
```

**BleService:**

```
public class BleService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = BleService.class.getSimpleName();

    private Map<String, BleDeviceInstanceData> connectedDeviceMap;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;

    private static int numInstances=0;
    // Bluetooth objects that we need to interact with

    // variables to track values set on SensorBug device

    private boolean mConnected=false;
    private final IBinder mBinder;

    public BleService() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Created a new BleService instance");
        mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    }

    BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {

            Log.d(TAG, "OnConnectionStateChange status="+status+ "deviceAddr="+ gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
            if (status == GATT_SUCCESS) {
                BluetoothDevice device = gatt.getDevice();
                String address = device.getAddress();

                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server");

                    if (!connectedDeviceMap.containsKey(address)) {
                        BleDeviceInstanceData bleDeviceInstanceData = new BleDeviceInstanceData();
                        bleDeviceInstanceData.mBluetoothGatt = gatt;
                        connectedDeviceMap.put(address, bleDeviceInstanceData);
                    }
                    // Broadcast if needed
                    Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                            gatt.discoverServices());

                } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                    if (connectedDeviceMap.containsKey(address)){
                        BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt = connectedDeviceMap.get(address).mBluetoothGatt;
                        if( bluetoothGatt != null ){
                            bluetoothGatt.close();
                            connectedDeviceMap.get(address).mBluetoothGatt = null;
                        }
                        connectedDeviceMap.remove(address);
                        broadcastUpdate(Constant.ACTION_DISCONNECTED);
                    }

                }

            } else {

                Log.e("BLE", "onConnectionStateChanged error "+status);
                // error
            }
        }

        /**
         * This is called when a service discovery has completed.
         *
         * It gets the characteristics we are interested in and then
         * broadcasts an update to the main activity.
         *
         * @param gatt The GATT database object
         * @param status Status of whether the write was successful.
         */
        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            // Get just the service that we are looking for
            BluetoothDevice device = gatt.getDevice();
            String address = device.getAddress();
            BleDeviceInstanceData bleDeviceInstanceData = connectedDeviceMap.get(address);
            bleDeviceInstanceData.mGattLightService = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString(Constant.BR_LightServiceUUID));
            bleDeviceInstanceData.mUuidServiceList = gatt.getServices();

            /* Get characteristics from our desired service */
//            mLightDataCharacteristic = mService.get(iCurrent).getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(BR_LightSrv_DataCharUUID));
//            mLightConfigCharacteristic = mService.get(iCurrent).getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(BR_LightSrv_ConfigCharUUID));

            /* Get the SensorBug CCCD */
//            mLightDataCccd = mLightDataCharacteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(CccdUUID));

            // Broadcast that service/characteristic/descriptor discovery is done
            broadcastUpdate(Constant.ACTION_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        }

        /**
         * This is called when a read completes
         *
         * @param gatt the GATT database object
         * @param characteristic the GATT characteristic that was read
         * @param status the status of the transaction
         */
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {

            if (status == GATT_SUCCESS) {
                BluetoothDevice device = gatt.getDevice();
                String address = device.getAddress();
                BleDeviceInstanceData bleDeviceInstanceData = connectedDeviceMap.get(address);

                // Verify that the read was the LED state
                String uuid = characteristic.getUuid().toString();
                // In this case, the only read the app does is the LED state.
                // If the application had additional characteristics to read we could
                // use a switch statement here to operate on each one separately.
                if (uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.BR_LightSrv_DataCharUUID)) {
                    bleDeviceInstanceData.mLightData = characteristic.getValue();
                }

                if (uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.BR_LightSrv_ConfigCharUUID)) {
                    bleDeviceInstanceData.mLightConfig = characteristic.getValue();
                }

                if (uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.BR_LightSrv_AlertCharUUID)) {
                    bleDeviceInstanceData.mLightAlert = characteristic.getValue();
                }
                // Notify the main activity that new data is available
                broadcastUpdate(Constant.ACTION_DATA_RECEIVED);
            } else {
                Log.e("BLE", "OnCharacteristicRead error status="+status+" gatt device addr="+gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
            }
        }

        /**
         * This is called when a characteristic with notify set changes.
         * It broadcasts an update to the main activity with the changed data.
         *
         * @param gatt The GATT database object
         * @param characteristic The characteristic that was changed
         */
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

            BluetoothDevice device = gatt.getDevice();
            String address = device.getAddress();
            BleDeviceInstanceData bleDeviceInstanceData = connectedDeviceMap.get(address);

            String uuid = characteristic.getUuid().toString();

            // In this case, the only notification the apps gets is the CapSense value.
            // If the application had additional notifications we could
            // use a switch statement here to operate on each one separately.
            if (uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.BR_LightSrv_DataCharUUID)) {
                bleDeviceInstanceData.mLightData = characteristic.getValue();
            }

            // Notify the main activity that new data is available
            broadcastUpdate(Constant.ACTION_DATA_RECEIVED);
        }

        /**
         * Sends a broadcast to the listener in the main activity.
         *
         * @param action The type of action that occurred.
         */
        private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

    };


    private static int oncreatecount=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        connectedDeviceMap = new HashMap<String, BleDeviceInstanceData>();
        mBluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        oncreatecount++;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BleService getService() {
            return BleService.this;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // The BLE close method is called when we unbind the service to free up the resources.

        connectedDeviceMap.forEach(
                (K, V) -> V.mBluetoothGatt.close()
        );
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    public boolean initialize() {
        return true;
    }

    public void connectToDevice(String deviceAddress) {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG,"BleService.connectToDevice devAddr="+deviceAddress);

            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
            int connectionState = mBluetoothManager.getConnectionState(device, BluetoothProfile.GATT);

            if (connectionState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                // connect your device
                device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
            } else if (connectionState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                // already connected . send Broadcast if needed

                Method m = device.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("connectGatt", Context.class, boolean.class, BluetoothGattCallback.class, int.class);
                int transport = device.getClass().getDeclaredField("TRANSPORT_LE").getInt(null);
                m.invoke(device, this, false, mGattCallback, transport);
            }

        } catch(IllegalAccessException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(InvocationTargetException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    /**
     * Runs service discovery on the connected device.
     */
    public void discoverServices(String deviceAddress) {
        BleDeviceInstanceData bleDeviceInstanceData=connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress);
        if (bleDeviceInstanceData==null) return;

        if (connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress).mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothGatt not initialized");
            return;
        }
        connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress).mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
    }

    /**
     * Disconnects an existing connection or cancel a pending connection. The disconnection result
     * is reported asynchronously through the
     * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
     * callback.
     */
    public void disconnect(String deviceAddress) {
        BleDeviceInstanceData bleDeviceInstanceData=connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress);
        if (bleDeviceInstanceData==null) return;

        if (connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress).mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress).mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    }

    /**
     * After using a given BLE device, the app must call this method to ensure resources are
     * released properly.
     */
    public void close(String deviceAddress) {
        BleDeviceInstanceData bleDeviceInstanceData=connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress);
        if (bleDeviceInstanceData==null) return;

        if (connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress).mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress).mBluetoothGatt.close();
        connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress).mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }

    /**
     * Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
     * connection change and services discovered.
     */

    public boolean readLightDataCharacteristic(String deviceAddress) {

        BleDeviceInstanceData bleDeviceInstanceData=connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress);
        if (bleDeviceInstanceData==null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "readLightDataCharacteristic DeviceInstanceData==null devAddr="+deviceAddress);
            return false;
        }

        if (bleDeviceInstanceData.mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return false;
        }
        BluetoothGattService btGattService = bleDeviceInstanceData.mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString(Constant.BR_LightServiceUUID));

        BluetoothGattCharacteristic btchar = btGattService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(Constant.BR_LightSrv_DataCharUUID));
        boolean result=bleDeviceInstanceData.mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(btchar);
        if (!result) {
            Log.e(TAG, "readCharacteristic returned false deviceAddr="+deviceAddress);
        }
        return result;
    }


    public byte[] getLightData(String deviceAddress) {
        BleDeviceInstanceData bleDeviceInstanceData=connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress);
        if (bleDeviceInstanceData==null) return null;

        return connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress).mLightData;
    }


    public List<BluetoothGattService> getServicelist(String deviceAddress) {
        BleDeviceInstanceData bleDeviceInstanceData=connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress);
        if (bleDeviceInstanceData==null) return null;

        return connectedDeviceMap.get(deviceAddress).mUuidServiceList;
    }





    /**
     * Sends a broadcast to the listener in the main activity.
     *
     * @param action The type of action that occurred.
     */
    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

**BleDeviceInstanceData:**

```
public class BleDeviceInstanceData {
    public BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
    public BluetoothGattService mGattLightService;
    public List<BluetoothGattService> mUuidServiceList;

    public byte[] mLightData;

    //  private static BluetoothGattCharacteristic mLightConfigCharacteristic;
    public byte[] mLightConfig;

    //    private static BluetoothGattCharacteristic mLightAlertCharacteristic;
    public byte[] mLightAlert;
}
```

When I run the app, I scan for devices and then loop through my list of target device addresses and call BleService.connect to the device to populate my Map of BLE devices.  Then I try to read characteristic data from one of the devices.  I am always able to read the data from the first device that I connected to whether it is the first read characteristic call or not. When I call read characteristic on a device from the second connection to a device, the read characteristic succeeds, but I get the less than useful status==129 error in the onCharacteristicRead callback.

Do I need to re-establish the connection via device.connectGatt each time I want to read/write data to a BLE device?  I hope not as I was planning to enable characteristic notifications on multiple devices to enable my app to watch and view data from multiple BLE devices at once.

Thanks for your help.  Let me know if you need more code.  I hope I've included enough relevant parts.

Comment: From the Android point of view this should work fine. You don't have to reconnect before each read. Have you tried if it works to do the same in for example the nRF Connect app?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  nRF Connect app has same issue (status 129 in log) on attempting to read characteristic from 2nd connected device.  Does this imply an Android issue or a lack of support for multiple connections on my device?  I'll try another phone (Google Pixel 4.2 later today)